# How to place an icon before a text?

Tags: html, css, icons, pseudo-element

I want to place an icon before the "Mon compte" text on my website.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<a href="/user" class="secondary-nav__menu-link secondary-nav__menu-link--link secondary-nav__menu-link--level-1" data-drupal-link-system-path="user">
  Mon compte
</a>
```

Here is my CSS code :

```
#block-useraccountmenu a::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("/themes/subtheme_olivero/images/person-circle.svg?itok=5") no-repeat;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

It works fine, here is the output :

[image]

My problem is that when I right click on the link, the icon is positioned in the middle of the text. I don't understand why the rendering changes like this :

[image]

If I click next to it, the icon repositions correctly. How to correct this problem ? What's wrong with my CSS code ? Thanks

**UPDATE**

If I apply the CSS to "a" the icon centers over the text, when right clicking on the text.

If I apply CSS to "li" it works fine, but I want the face icon to be part of the link.

Small clarification, I can't modify the HTML code and I don't want to use an external library for a single icon.

Comment: may we have the code? #block-useraccountmenu isn't present and nothing is reproducible!

Comment: your code works. the problem must be elsewhere

Comment: May you add a snippet???

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it might be easier to use Font Awesome. First insert the `CDN`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/>
```

Then head over to their [icon page](https://fontawesome.com/icons) and select an icon (Make sure it's not a 'pro' icon). It seems like this is the one you are going for:

```html
<i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
```

After that, it's easy. Just paste that line (or a different icon) before your text:

```html
<a href="/user" class="secondary-nav__menu-link secondary-nav__menu-link--link secondary-nav__menu-link--level-1" data-drupal-link-system-path="user">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Mon compte
</a>
```

That's it! You might need to style it using `font-size` and other rules.

## Edit:

The most you can reduce the content of the `CDN` is like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/solid.min.css"/>
```

Although this method has 2 `URL`s, its much better than the first method.

Comment: @Mathieu, you can turn the icon I suggest into the one you want by adding `border-radius: 51%;` and `border: 2px solid #000000;` to the icon's `CSS`

Comment: I don't want CBN loaded or use library for single icon

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a background image, you can try using the img element instead.  Code would look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.input-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="input-container">
    <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="50" height="60">
    <div class="input-field"> Mon compte </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't edit HTML code, only CSS code

Comment: Please try adding background-position in your background property > background: url("/themes/subtheme_olivero/images/person-circle.svg?itok=5") no-repeat left center;

Comment: Hi Mathieu,  if the site is cocorinet.fr, I can't seem to find the My Account link.  The other links with icons seems to be working well.  If this is not the site, please do share.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Mathieu,  I see it now.  Can you please confirm that (1) application looks different when using Chrome and Edge and (2) problem is in Edge only; you've tried in Chrome and it's working.  Thanks.   (Chrome) https://ibb.co/CBnTL2w
(Edge) https://ibb.co/YDY0knG
(Edge with issue) https://ibb.co/WWMZWvC

Comment: HI @Mathieu, was able to isolate the problem encountered.  It seems to be caused by the ::before selector.  I removed the selector and did not encounter the problem anymore.  Hope this helps.